# SQL Query: Get String with highest number | Parse?

Tags: php, mysql, string, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a database which looks like this:
[image]

Do not ask my why, but this is written by a WordPress plugin so I have to handle with it. What I want is to get every link where the meta_key = `product_shops_X_link`. But every post has a variable amount of product shop links.

In this picture I tried `Where meta_key Like "%_link%"`. But if I do a query like that I also get all meta_keys where the `product_shops_X_link` field has a `_` before the `product`...

What I want is just all `product_shops_X_link` fields. Now there a two ways I think.

Way 1: Get the highest number of the meta key fields `Where meta_key Like "%product_shops_X_link%" OR meta_key Like "%_product_shops_X_link%"`. It doesn't matter of `_product` or just `product`. The numbers are equal. If there is just a `product_shops_0_link` field there must be also a `_product_shops_0_link` field.

Way2: Create a pattern which only searches for all `product_shops_X_link` fields without the beginning of `_product` and give me ALL `product_shops_X_link` fields. Whatever number is contained in the field.

But in both cases I do not know how to code that..
Does anyone knows how to code that or is there maybe a better way?

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: How about using `WHERE meta_key LIKE 'product_shops_%_link'`?

Comment: @IgorJerosimić Note that `_` is a placeholder for a single character in a LIKE expression.

Comment: I found a easier way: `SELECT COUNT(meta_key) AS CNT, post_id FROM fWR6qIN_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE 'product_shops_%_link'`. But how can I add some more attributes to the query like `post_id` or `meta_key`. Actual I just see a number and it is working. But if I add some attributes, I get a error?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want entries starting with `_product` then you can exclude `_` or `%` from your `LIKE` pattern, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM links
WHERE meta_key LIKE 'product_%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I am misunderstanding but are you trying to capture the number from those rows? If so, you can use the native `REPLACE()` function like this:

```
SELECT *, REPLACE(REPLACE(meta_key, 'product_shops_', ''),'_link','') as captured_number
FROM mytable
WHERE meta_key LIKE 'product\_shops\_%\_link'
ORDER BY captured_number DESC
```

This will get you the rows you want with the highest number first.  Alternately you can use [this regex library](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg) for mysql and then use regex to capture the number:

```
SELECT *, PREG_CAPTURE( '/product_shops_([0-9]+)/', meta_key) as captured_number
FROM mytable
WHERE meta_key LIKE 'product\_shops\_%\_link'
ORDER BY captured_number DESC
```

Comment: No, thats right. But my SQL says: "Function PREG_CAPTURE doesn't exists"

Comment: you need to install the library mentioned in my answer to use `preg_capture()`.  it might seem like a lot of effort but in the long run I think you'll find it useful.

Comment: @FrazeJr. - I've updated my answer using native mysql function.

Answer (score 0):

> But how can I add some more attributes to the query like post_id or
>   meta_key

Those can be combined with `AND`, for example to query items with `post_id = 21179` and `meta_key` starts with `product_..`:

```
SELECT myFields
FROM myTable
WHERE (post_id = 21179) AND (meta_key LIKE 'product_shops_%')
```